# Issue with reading and storing data from .txt file into array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, double

Program:

1. User enters a file name containing numbers (1 per line)
2. File is read and data is stored in StringBuffer
3. StringBuffer is converted to String type
4. String is split() and stored in a String[]
5. Double[] is created and converts/stores elements of the String[]

The above is what I am trying to achieve; however, the program is not working.
*Look below for an example...

```
class tester
{
public static int x = 0;
public static double[] dataArray = new double[x];//array storing elements

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //userInput .txt
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter filename:\n");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    File file = new File(name);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String newString = stringBuffer.toString();

    String [] stringArray = newString.split("\n");
    double [] dataArray = new double[stringArray.length];

    for(int i=0 ; i < stringArray.length ; i++)
    {  
        dataArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i]);  
    }
```

I have a file named: Ben.txt that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

When I run the program...

```
Enter filename:

c:/Ben.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at tester.main(tester.java:27)
```

Comment: Each number in Ben.txt is on its own line (1 \n 2 \n 3)

Comment: You are not reading the file. You are just creating the buffer, splitting the empty string and trying to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not actually reading anything from the file. You do all the setup but you aren't reading.

So when you have:

```
    File file = new File(name);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String newString = stringBuffer.toString();
```

Here I don't think you actually need a StringBuffer, all you have to add/replace is this

```
    String str;
    str = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

If you want to read the whole file all you have to do is iterate over the entire file using readLine().

Comment: Sorry, can you show me how to read the entire file? My programming knowledge is fairly limited currently.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but to iterate over it all you have to do is

        while( (str = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)

Answer (score 1):

As GiantTree said, you are not actually reading in the file at all

Changing the definition of newString to the following will give you some progress.

```
  String newString = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Other things you should consider:

- closing the resources you've opened
- exception handling
- following standard class naming conventions
- no need to initialise dataArray twice